# How to pass curl resource in jobs queue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

How to pass curl resource in jobs queue? but now curl not support for queue ,not response

enter code here

```
          $fields = json_encode($fields);
         $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications');
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8']);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

also am used laravel guzzlehttp

```
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications', [
                        'json' => $fields
                    ]);
```

```
class OneSignalJobs implements ShouldQueue
{  public function handle()
    {  $files=[]

        $fields = json_encode($fields);
        $url = "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications";
        $response = $client->createRequest("POST", $url, $fields);
        $response = $client->send($response);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $files);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = curl_exec($ch); }
```

Comment: pass what to queue job?

Comment: i have to send a notification for mobile ,so am add that notification on queue jobs with curl i mentioned above ,that curl not working in jobs when using command  php artisan queue:listen

Comment: i dont understand the "passing" the resource part, where are you passing what resource to?

Comment: am just created one job page OneSignalJobs  and called curl init and pass array data (json) after run queue not working curl ,that is my problem

Comment: alright I guess "pass curl resource in jobs queue" is not what you are doing

Comment: that curl not working in jobs page when run ,php artisan queue:listen

Comment: are the jobs failing? do you have the same php modules enabled on CLI as you do for FPM or the webserver?

Comment: show how you pass the "curl" to the job?

Comment: am added in the top section

Comment: now its working  fine